# How to find count of specific rows and other columns with different where condition in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is My Model Code:

```
function getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail($saleOrderId)
{
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;

$this->db->select('BaseTbl.itemId, count(CASE WHEN SaleOrder.orderDate >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND SaleOrder.orderDate <= curdate() THEN SaleOrder.orderDate ELSE NULL END) as totalOrderLast6Month');
$this->db->from('tbl_saleorderdetail as BaseTbl');
$this->db->join('tbl_saleorders as SaleOrder', 'SaleOrder.saleOrderId = BaseTbl.masterId','left');
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.masterId', $saleOrderId);
$this->db->order_by("BaseTbl.id", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
}
```

from this query i get each item of an sale order with its last 6 month sale record count with fixed where clause `$this->db->where('BaseTbl.masterId', $saleOrderId);`.
i want to get items of this where clause but also i need last 6 months record count of `all` sale orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail` twice.

First time with the condition and second time without condition

```
function getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail($saleOrderId = '')
{
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;

$this->db->select('BaseTbl.itemId, count(CASE WHEN SaleOrder.orderDate >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH) AND SaleOrder.orderDate <= curdate() THEN SaleOrder.orderDate ELSE NULL END) as totalOrderLast6Month');
$this->db->from('tbl_saleorderdetail as BaseTbl');
$this->db->join('tbl_saleorders as SaleOrder', 'SaleOrder.saleOrderId = BaseTbl.masterId','left');
if(!empty($saleOrderId)){
   $this->db->where('BaseTbl.masterId', $saleOrderId);
}
$this->db->order_by("BaseTbl.id", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
}
```

Now do like this

```
$counter = count($this->model_name->getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail());
```

This will count rows

```
$data = $this->model_name->getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail($saleOrderId);
```

This will give you data with condition

Comment: Thank You So much! but here you did little mistake `$counter = count($this->model_name->getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail());` it should be `$data['counter'] = $this->user_model->getSaleOrderFormInfoDetail();` because there are other columns are coming to in array.

Comment: do count can be specific to each product? like each product total count

Comment: @Danial thanks for the correction. Yes you can count for each product just need the product ID or name for the condition